# Not receiving notifications on dual WhatsApp on Samsung Note8

Tags: notifications, settings, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-note-8, samsung-dual-messenger

I have two instances of WhatsApp on my Note8. When I receive a message on my primary WhatsApp, I get notifications instantly as normal. However, on my dual WhatsApp, I don't get notifications unless I open the app.

Sometimes, I get notifications come in all of a sudden as if the app has come alive and checked, but this is not consistent with the primary app.

I've gone to *Settings->Notifications* and there is only one 'WhatsApp' app listed and notifications are enabled. However, this cannot be where the issue is as the notifications are fine for the primary app, just not the dual app.

If I go to *Settings->Apps*, then here I do see both instances listed. And notifications are enabled for both. I've also checked the *Mobile data* settings for both, and they both have *Allow background data usage* enabled. I am not using *Data saver*.

The only thing I've not tried is disabling *Optimise battery usage* for WhatsApp as this seems to be for both instances of the app, not either. But other than that possibility, I'm stumped. Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: Do you have two sims?

Comment: @RohitGupta Of course. But this is no longer an issue as this was nearly 4 years ago. I have a Samsung Z Fold3 now which handles dual messengers much better, possibly owing to later versions of Android and/or WhatsApp. It was probably due to the power saving settings of the apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your phone power saving app is putting a dual messenger app to sleep. so please check that it's not in sleep app list.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with getting notifications for my dual Viber app and it seems that by default they are turned off.

So, you need to go to *Notifications > Advanced* and there you could find and manage your dual messenger's notifications.

[image]

I'm not sure that the path will be the same for your device but for the record I'm using Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0.0 on it.

Maybe that could help you with the issue.